# How to fix the symbol not found error in my code

Tags: java, symbol-not-found

```
// An illustration of object creation.
class ShipMain1 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
    // Define a method variable to refer to a Ship object.
    Ship argo;
    // Construct a new Ship object.
    argo = new Ship();
    }
}
```

When I go to compile it, it tells me symbol can not be found for the Ship in both *Ship argo* and *argo = new Ship();* please help I'm an extremely new beginner. I'm also copying this out of a programming book so I don't know why it's not working.

Comment: Where is the code where you define Ship?

Comment: Your compiler is not finding the Ship class.

Answer (score 0):

An object is an instance of a class. You need thus to have a class defined somewhere. In your case, you certainly forgot to copy the `Ship` class.

You can just create the missing class the same way you created   `ShipMain1`. No need to create any method. The following should work.

```
public class Ship{}
```

A faster solution is to use the class where the `main` method is defined. You can rename the class `ShipMain1` to `Ship` or  set  a argo as an instance of  `ShipMain1`.

Comment: Thank you for some reason the book kept telling me to type class ShipMain1 but as soon as i changed it to Ship it compiled

Answer (score 0):

An object is an instant of a class, if you want to perform instantiation you have to declare the class somewhere in that folder as a new class which defines Ship with a constructor ship() which defines ship.
And After that you can call it.

```
public class Ship
{
  public Ship(int a, int b)
  {
   sizeOfShip = a;
   sizeOfSails = b;
  }
}
```

After declaring this class you can declare a new instant of this class in further program or in any other class.